# Odd NSNumber Output - Core Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-data

When Following the CoreDataBooks sample code and implementing it into my app, I have reached a very odd bug/glitch with an NSNumber(Integer 16).

When I have the code

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", child.marblesneeded];
```

the detailTextLabel  displays an odd string of numbers that changes every time I try to change the numbers. See Attached Image. Currently, it should display 0 but it displays 112917120.[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSNumber has a method to return you the number as string, which can be used as a label text, as follows:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [child.marblesneeded stringValue];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [child.marblesneeded intValue]];
```